# VBA Formatting to accounting format

Tags: excel, vba, number-formatting

I'm trying to get VBA to format a cell in the "accounting" format (in Euro). I have copied the format from the options which shows

```
_-* #.##0,00 €_-;-* #.##0,00 €_-;_-* "-"?? €_-;_-@_-
```

When I try to apply this to

```
.Cells(1, 1).NumberFormat = "_-* #.##0,00 €_-;-* #.##0,00 €_-;_-* " - "?? €_-;_-@_-"
```

I get a 400 error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double-up those double quotes *(inside a string variable)*:

```
Sub kjdsffh()
    With ActiveSheet
        s = "_-* #.##0,00 €_-;-* #.##0,00 €_-;_-* ""-""?? €_-;_-@_-"
        .Cells(1, 1).NumberFormat = s
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Easier than thought!

Comment: Your welcome. Slight followup question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53468715/vba-formatting-issue